# Including jar in EJB module with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm using Eclipse.

In my J2EE application I included `jt400.jar` as an external `jar` to my build path, but when I try to connect from code I get the exception:

`class not found exception com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Was the jar contains the class AS400JDBCDriver  ? if not use jar to solve this error[Here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/jarClasses/41375)

Comment: Yes the jar contains the class AS400JDBCDriver

Answer (score 1):

I  added a lib folder under EarContent folder and put the jar into it. It works fine.